# Mustache Template doesn't render inside table tbody

Tags: javascript, json, templates, mustache

Why is that the same JSON object code generates the output with `ul` elements, but not with a `table` tag.

I have my Mustache template like:

```
<div id="template-ul">
    <h3>{{name}}</h3>
    <ul>
        {{#students}}
        <li>{{name}} - {{age}}</li>
        {{/students}}
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="template-table">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {{#students}}
            <tr>
                <td>{{name}}</td>
                <td>{{age}}</td>
            </tr>
        {{/students}}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Here is the javascript code:

```
var testing = {
    "name" : "student-collection",
    "students" : [
        {
            "name" : "John",
            "age" : 23
        },
        {
            "name" : "Mary",
            "age" : 21
        }
    ]
};

var divUl = document.getElementById("template-ul");
var divTable = document.getElementById("template-table");

divUl.innerHTML = Mustache.render(divUl.innerHTML, testing);
divTable.innerHTML = Mustache.render(divTable.innerHTML, testing);
```

Here is the code on jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/pRSjH/2/

Comment: Please change the "name : John" to "fname : Mary", this won't solve the bigger problem, but will prevent the useless student-collections printed in table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`divTable.innerHTML` returns [this](http://pastebin.com/FW2vKxGU) instead of correct template.
Probably it's happens because browser tries to render invalid HTML. I think you can put your template into `<script>` tag to solve this problem ([the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/superhacker/pRSjH/5/))

Comment: Hey thanks. That works. And what I did was, create a separate table.tpl file and fetched it on the fly and when it was loaded, rendered the templated with the data.

Answer (score 34):

You can also **comment mustache tags** in tbody. And table will built correctly.
My template example:

```
<div id="template-table">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <!--{{#students}}-->
            <tr>
                <td>{{name}}</td>
                <td>{{age}}</td>
            </tr>
        <!--{{/students}}-->
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```