# Creating dynamic tables from JSON using templates (HTML)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, templates, mustache

I'm trying to parse a JSON object into an html table using JavaScript. I found several examples ([Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24923871/json-object-into-mustache-js-table), [Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15585819/mustache-template-doesnt-render-inside-table-tbody) and many others for JS and tables in general), **but they all work for JSON objects that are formatted as array of objects (dictionaries)**. The format I am working with is pretty much an *array of arrays*. However, the parsing works quite differently. For example, one promising library, mustache.js is heavily dependent upon tag keys which become variables in the templates. Examples I've found using [jQuery](http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2010/11/30/an-introduction-to-jquery-templates) to generate tables also seem to need data to be formatted as an array of dictionaries.

Is mustache/jQuery not suitable for parsing a JSON document like this? If not, any recommendations on approach that produces clean, fast, maintainable code? (Assumptions: I am already including Bootstrap/jQuery and any additional framework must be able to coexist with those. The table size might be on the order of 100x100 cells).

JSON:

```
{
  "col_hdr": [ "COL1", "COL2", "COL3" ],
  "data": [
    [ "ROW1-COL1", "ROW1-COL2", "ROW1-COL3" ],
    [ "ROW2-COL1", "ROW2-COL2", "ROW2-COL3" ]
  ]
}
```

Which using JavaScript I want to turn into this in HTML:

```
<table id="my_table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>COL1</th>
          <th>COL2</th>
          <th>COL3</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>ROW1-COL1</td>
          <td>ROW1-COL1</td>
          <td>ROW1-COL1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>ROW2-COL2</td>
          <td>ROW2-COL2</td>
          <td>ROW2-COL2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>ROW3-COL3</td>
          <td>ROW3-COL3</td>
          <td>ROW3-COL3</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: http://json2html.com/

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24923871

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are having with Mustache?

Comment: mustache likes JSON to be in dictionary form (the keys in the dictionaries => variable names in template) (see Q2 (link in first paragraph) for a simple example), whereas I'm trying to parse an array of arrays. At first glance, the json2html seems to suffer from the same limitation.

Comment: Mustache is able to render object literals. In your case it may require nested views, similar to `{{#arr1}}{{#nestedArr}}<!-- Content -->{{/nestedArr}}{{#arr1}}`